# Error when getting rid of cx_Freeze Console

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

So i am developing game on python using pygame and now i finally finished and went on to converting my game to an executable and encountered with a problem which was that the python kept opening when i run the game. I did my research and fixed that by this code:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":  <-- This Fixed it
    base = "Win32GUI" <----- ^^

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("dodgethat.py",icon=r"icon1.ico", base = base)

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Dodge That!",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame","LeaderBoardManager","ServerManager","UserManager"],
                       "include_files":["images","fonts"]}},
    executables = executables

)
```

But after all this i am getting another error when i close the game, which is as following

[Error Message Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bCXx.png)

Pygame quit code

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit()
```

Comment: What is this 'quit'? Can you show us the code please?

Comment: I've edited the post and the code is there now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function quit is unknown unless you didn't implement it by yourself. So I think you want to use `pygame.quit()` here:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It's giving another error for some video initialization after i press quit. I dont think there is a fix for it... "pygame.error: Video system not initialised"

Comment: Call `pygame.init()` somewhere at the top of your script

Comment: @SameerAli Everything fine now?